# Найти пары слов с совпадением последней буквы и первой

Tags: java

Попалась задача, условие таково:

> В методе getLine используя StringBuilder расставить все слова в таком порядке,
>   чтобы последняя буква данного слова совпадала с первой буквой следующего не учитывая регистр.

Мой код метода:

```
public static StringBuilder getLine(String... words)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words)
    {
        if(word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length()-1))
        {
            sb.append(word).append(" ");
        }
    }
      return sb;
}
```

Не понимаю как сравнить последнюю букву с первой буквой следующего слова.
Пока, что мой метод сравнивает первую и последнюю букву в каждом слове и выводит на экран все слова в которых первая и последняя буквы одинаковые, но мне нужно чтобы он сравнивал только последнюю букву данного слова и первую букву следующего. Подскажите в каком направлении копать.
PS: Задачу выполняю на Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте структуру для быстрого обращения к элементам. Например ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : words)
   arrayList.add(word);
```

Затем обращайтесь в цикле к нужному элементу с помощью функции get().

```
arrayList.get(j)
```

---

Вот для примера код который возвращает слова, у которых последняя буква совпадает с первой буквой следующего слова.

```
public class SO {
    public static StringBuilder getLine2( String... words) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String word : words)
            arrayList.add(word);
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (arrayList.get(j).charAt(arrayList.get(j).length() - 1) == arrayList.get(j + 1).charAt(0))
                sb.append(arrayList.get(j)).append(" ");
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SO so = new SO();
        StringBuilder sb = new SO().getLine2( "acab", "bca", "dfg", "gfh");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Вернет

```
acab dfg
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но есть один нюанс, мне необходимо вывести слова в таком порядке чтобы последняя буква слова совпадала с первой буквой следующего слова к примеру входные данные: "acab, dfg bcd gfd" - результат должен получится таким: "acab bcd dfg gfd" и так далее.

Comment: Разобрался достаточно было изменить одну строчку, ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Можно вроде еще с помощью объекта Comparator отсортировать по условию. Но почему-то в данном случае срабатывало :)

Comment: Я воспользовался Collections.shuffle :)